# Transactional Email

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail

Logo on **transactional emails** are showing **default logo**. I have tried your change in **back end** and **file manager** on **c panel**.

Anyone know what to do?

---

Below is taken from email template header. Is there any of it that I could change, to change the source of the logo?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <style type="text/css">
        {{var template_styles|raw}}

        {{css file="css/email.css"}}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
{{inlinecss file="css/email-inline.css"}}

<!-- Begin wrapper table -->
<table class="wrapper" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapper-inner" align="center">
            <table class="main" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="header">
                        <a class="logo" href="{{store url=""}}">
                            <img
                                {{if logo_width}}
                                    width="{{var logo_width}}"
                                {{else}}
                                    width="180"
                                {{/if}}

                                {{if logo_height}}
                                    height="{{var logo_height}}"
                                {{else}}
                                    height="52"
                                {{/if}}

                                src="{{var logo_url}}"
                                alt="{{var logo_alt}}"
                                border="0"
                            />
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="main-content">
                    <!-- Begin Content -->
```

Comment: Phil, Have u changed logo from   Content > Design > Configuration>Transactional Email Then you need deploy static content

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-change-email-logo-magento-2.html

Comment: Thanks for replying Amit Bera. When I save configuration after uploading image and then come back it shows as a broken link/image. How do deploy static content?